# tag:census vs. us-census

Tags: discussion, tags

So, I should have posted this before I did it, but I noticed that the application of the `census` tag was pretty diverse, in a way which wasn't very helpful. The "tag wiki" summary was not very helpful, and the [full explanation of the tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/census/info) suggests co-tagging with a specific place (e.g. [usa]).

This doesn't seem to be of much use, as tags are meant to help people find questions. I would think that a single specific tag is much more effective than combining tags.

> **EDIT:** I should say, "in this case." I noticed, for example, tags like `language` and `japanese` and can see a case for using those as
>   they are currently. Interest in language is sometimes a flag which
>   transcends specific boundaries. Interest in "census" (especially as
>   minimally-defined in the tag wiki/excerpt) is not really a thing, as
>   best I can tell.

Therefore, I created a new tag, `us-census` and wrote a [tag wiki entry](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/us-census/info) for it, and changed the tag on most of the extant questions using the `census` tag.

Next time I'll post here first but... any objections?

Comment: The uk has a similar project http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/census-records/, as does Australia for its historic censuses ... should we not have similar tags for these as well?

Comment: I would tend to agree with that approach, especially if there are questions here which clearly require answers from people knowledgeable in those data products.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start by saying that every effort to raise the quality here on Open Data SE is much appreciated :)

In this case, however, I have some reservations.

> the application of the census tag was pretty diverse

In what way? As far as I can tell, all [census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census) questions are about census data one way or another. If not, then the tag should be removed from the respective question.

> The "tag wiki" summary was not very helpful

Improvements are always welcome :)

> Interest in "census" (especially as minimally-defined in the tag wiki/excerpt) is not really a thing

An under-defined tag is one thing. However I wouldn't go so far as to say that there is no interest in [census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census) questions outside of the US.

Now to your proposed [us-census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) tag. I currently see a few issues:

- As a non-US citizen it took me quite a while to realize that [us-census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) refers to [an institution](http://census.gov/) and is not just a combination of a country ([usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)) and a topic ([census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census)).
- Currently 5 people follow the [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) tag. If we remove this tag from all of the [us-census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) questions, then these 5 people won't see those questions highlighted any longer, although they would be very relevant. On the other hand, co-tagging all [us-census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) questions with [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) seems pretty redundant. (This is basically the same dilemma that we have with the [data.gov](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data.gov) tag.)

I get your point that currently people cannot favorite questions that deal specifically with the US Census (although they can of course favorite or ignore [usa](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) and [census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census) separately). Searching, on the other hand, is not a problem: `[usa] [census]` has exactly the same effect as `[us-census]` and is only 3 characters longer.

One idea might be to think of the [us-census](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-census) tag as an equivalent to the [data.gov](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data.gov) tag. In that case, however, I'd suggest that we call it [census.gov](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/census.gov) to avoid any confusion and limit it to questions dealing with US Census specifics.

In any case, I look forward to hearing how others think about this.

Comment: Why do we use tags? I have favorite tags to help me find questions I might learn from, or help answer. As it was being used, the census tag was not helpful in either case, or no more helpful than being more specific. Also, I have little sympathy for the theoretical scaling problem: the US Census Bureau is a major provider of open data. There will be many questions about its products. The other examples you offer are not countries which have, as far as I know, extensive census data or communities looking for/offering help.

Comment: Regarding people who follow the "census" tag, how many of them care about non-US-census? The interest is because it was the only game in town.

Comment: I have to admit that as a non-US citizen, I wasn't aware of the fact that "US Census" is actually the name of an institution and not just the combination of a country and a topic. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I was about to raise a question on the very question. I think there will be lots of confusion around the meaning of [us-census] and merging with [data.gov]. Just looking at the common usage of the [census] tag, when it is used in the US, it is often used with both the [usa] and the [us-census] tags, which then takes out the value of the [us-census] as a single tag. When people from other countries use it they use [germany][census] or [france][census]

Comment: @MarcusD I haven't been following the Meta board much -- but I'm not following your comment here. Is there a proposal to merge [us-census] and [data.gov]? I would probably argue against that. I stand by my model for how tags are useful, and would refer to the many product-specific tags on Stack Overflow itself as an example, and refer to my answer to your other comment for more...